# QML Dialog which is at the bottom of all others qml dialogs?

Tags: qt, dialog, qml

How to create QML Dialog, which is at the bottom of all others QML dialogs in main ApplicationWindow of my program? I want every time when I make that QML Dialog visible (from C++ part of my program) to be at the bottom of all others opened Dialogs in main ApplicationWindow of my program.

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: You could try with the z position for those dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Scab My idea was something like to create my own QML element, based on QML Dialog and use that QML element everytime I need Dialog. Every openend instantion (when visible becomes true) of that custom QML dialog takes unique number (that number represents the stacking order of opened dialogs) . When dialog that must be under all others dialogs becomes visible, it emits signal that reopen all others opened dialogs in right stacking order. That is how that dialog going at the bottom of all others dialogs. This is ugly, not elegant and it is my "last hope".

Tarod thank you. This is brilliant and perfect solution. z: -1 :D Shamefull moment for me.